# How to draw a non uniformly scaled 3D sphere（ellipsoid） using point sprite in modern GLSL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to render a **non uniformly scaled sphere**(**ellipsoid**) using point sprite in GLSL 440 or GLSL version higher than 330.

As we know, the point sprite in GLSL, can easily draw a unit sphere, but it's difficult to draw a ellipsoid with special requirements.

My thoughts are as follows:

1. Firstly, I have a point(center of the sphere);
2. Then, render a unit sphere using the point sprite;
3. Suppose that the sphere is transformed by a rotate-scale matrix(non uniformly scaled);
4. Then the transformed ellipsoid is rendered on the screen. reference: [Line-ellipsoid intersection](http://www.illusioncatalyst.com/notes_files/mathematics/line_nu_sphere_intersection.php)

In old OpenGL version, the function **glutSloidSphere()** in **GLUT** lib can easily realize this, but how can I code in the modern OpenGL 4.x using fragment shader? 
Thanks a lot!

The final effect I want is similar to the one shown below.

[image: Effect Image01]

[image: Effect Image02]

Comment: I never used point sprites but there are more ways how to do this see these: [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214) and [How can i make gradient sphere on glsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442375/2521214) and [How to draw 3D point verts without generating geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158783/2521214).

Comment: so Either use geometry shader to emit geometry per each point or pass data as Texture ... rendering is done by form of raytrace see [raytrace through 3D mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) .... so read all linked QAs chose the best approach for you and let us know so we know on what focus our answers ... Also do you got a sample input (the ellipsoids in ASCII ... ideally a C++ array definition with data)

Comment: "*In old OpenGL version, the function glutSloidSphere() in GLUT lib can easily realize this, but how can I code in the modern OpenGL 4.x using fragment shader?*" glutSolidSphere created a *mesh*. Using point sprites and a fragment shader would mean ray tracing. Why not just create a sphere mesh yourself, just like glutSolidSphere did?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have more than 1 million points to render , so it may be expensive to create a sphere mesh for each point myself.