# How to use char string in GLSL?

Tags: char, glsl

How to use char sumbols from GLSL? Test on https://www.shadertoy.com/new .

```
int c = int('a'); // Not work
```

How to get one sumbol or string? For call function.

```
DrawString("Hello world!"); // Example
```

I can do this, but it's so hard:

```
#define _H 72
DrawString(_H, _e, _l, _l, _o);
```

Comment: see my [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214). You can not have string as call parameter but you can have global text buffer where you have intermediate operands and stuff instead like I did in the linked QA...

Comment: @Spektre, my font project https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3s2cRc .

Answer (score 2):

String and character literals do not exist in GLSL. You can make integer arrays, where the array values represent characters of some kind, but that's about it.

Comment: see my [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214) you can have character literals but you're right you need to store them into `int`s ...