# Encoding 2 integers into RGBA without bitwise

Tags: opengl

I'm using Processing(Java) to write shaders that do lots of fancy code art.
In my shader code I'm trying to get 2 integers (x,y positions) into an RGBA so I can send this colored pixel back to my Java program - and from there decode this color to get back the original integers.
As far a I know, I cant use bitwise operations in GLSL, or least I'd have to re-write a lot of code.
So I need to get 2 numbers into an RGBA, or 1 number into 2 bytes (RG) and the other in another 2 bytes (BA) - something like that.. without bitwise.. Help!!

Comment: If you only have access to a 4byte rgba rendertarget, then you can't store 2 integers = 8byte. You can probably store 2 short. Getting the high and low byte shouldn't be a problem with shift operators (available in glsl > 130). I don't think it is possible to do what you want completely without bit manipulation. Also, don't forget to handle the sign.

Comment: but i could store 1 integer in 2 bytes (0....65536 range)? and another integer in the other 2 bytes.  I've seen it done in glsl on the web, but they use bit operations glsl 130 - maybe ill just try and use those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we must take into account the **MSB/LSB** order on **CPU** side and internal format of **GPU** render buffer. The simplest way to check the order is to set color in **GLSL** with different channels and read it on **CPU** side as hex number so:

1. **in GLSL set color to `vec4(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4);` (r,g,b,a)**
2. **read the color on CPU side and print it as HEX**

   the channels are:

   ```
   chn  float             BYTE
        [dec]             [hex]
   r =  0.1 -> 255*0.1 -> 19h
   g =  0.2 -> 255*0.1 -> 33h
   b =  0.3 -> 255*0.1 -> 4Ch
   a =  0.4 -> 255*0.1 -> 66h
   ```

   Your output was `0x6619334C` which identifies the order of `r,g,b,a` as:

   ```
   MSB ....... LSB
   66  19  33  4C  hex (4xBYTE)
   0.4 0.1 0.2 0.3 dec (4xfloat)
   a   r   g   b
   ```

   so we can encode x,y for example like this:

   ```
   MSB ....... LSB
   a   r   g   b
   Yh  Yl  Xh  Xl
   ```

   In case your `a` channel is not correct check if your render buffer has allocated 8 bits for alpha channel during OpenGL context creation (look for pixel format descriptor) and repair if not.

   In case you are using this for different render targets each can have different internal format so you need to check this for each separately.

Another problem is that your color on **GLSL** side is most likely a `vec4` and not integer type so you need to use `floats` ... Also `%` requires extention so to avoid that compute it by `/` like this:

```cpp
unsigned int x,y; // 2x16 bit integer
vec4 xy;          // 4xfloat (32 bit color)
unsigned int h,l; // temp

h=x/256u; l=x-(256u*h);
xy.b=float(l)/255.0;
xy.g=float(h)/255.0;
h=y/256u; l=y-(256u*h);
xy.r=float(l)/255.0;
xy.a=float(h)/255.0;
```

Now the extraction of `x,y` back on **CPU** side:

```cpp
unsigned int rgba; // input 32 bit color
unsigned int x,y;  // output 16 bit x,y
y=(rgba>>16)&0x0000FFFF;
x=(rgba    )&0x0000FFFF;
```

Comment: hey thanks this looks interesting - I did manage to get something similar working by splitting into rg, ba - but I think the precision was off a bit - I only needed a range of about 0-4000 for x,y - but the results had the odd error - I'll try yours to see if it improves. thanks..

Comment: @GlennMarshall You can use this [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214) to check the contents of your variables along the way.

Comment: that is super useful!

Comment: @GlennMarshall yep and really fun:)  just be sure that whole area where you print has the same GLSL outcome for printing otherwise it would be gibberish as each fragment can have different number for printing ... I would never get working stuff like this [GLSL ray tracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) without it ...

Comment: oh while you're there - can you help me with the code to extract the x,y values from the rgba above - im trying to this myself at the minute - in java

Comment: basically my shader draws the pixel onto a 1x1 quad - then in my java program - i read this pixel as 4x8 bit values - i.e. red =0...255 green 0..255 etc

Comment: here's the hex value of your vec4
6619334C

Comment: for that vec4 I get x=26137.0 y=13132.0  on my cpu

Comment: i think my processing/java software uses ARGB if thats useful

Comment: it works!
just implementing in my full program now to see there are no errors...

Comment: @GlennMarshall If the answer is solving your problem you should accept it (click on the checker in upper left corner of answer) for others to quickly see what solved your problem or if you still need an answer.. However do not accept if your problem is not fully solved. In such case comment to clarify/request what you need ... Once you got more reputation you will be able to also up/down vote to mark what is helpful and what not ...

Comment: it all works! 
my code now runs twice as fast
thank you so much..