# Does an any image file format support negative floats?

Tags: image, opengl

I'm using OpenGL for implementing some screen space filters. For debugging purposes, I would like to save a bunch of textures so a can compare individual pixel values. The problem is that these 16-bit float textures have negative values. Do you know of any image file formats that support negative values? How could I export them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are some such formats ... What you need is to use non clamped floating formats. This is what I am using:

```
GL_LUMINANCE32F_ARB
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE32F_ARB, size, size, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

Here an example:

- [raytrace through 3D mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214)

In there I am passing geometry in a float texture that is not clamped so it has full range not just `<0,1>` As you can see negative range is included too ...

There are few others but once I found the one was no point to look for more of them...

You can verify clamping using the [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214)

Also IIRC there was some function to set the clamping behavior of OpenGL but never used it (if my memory serves well).

**[Edit1] exporting to file**

this is a problem and unless yo are exporting to ASCII or math matrix files I do not know of any format supporting negative pixel values...

So you need to workaround... so simply convert range to non negative ones like this:

```
float max = ???; //some value that is safely bigger than biggest abs value in your images
for (each pixel x,y)
 {
 pixel(x,y) = 0.5*(max + pixel(x,y))
 }
```

and then converting back if needed

```
for (each pixel x,y)
 {
 pixel(x,y) = (2.0*pixel(x,y)-max);
 }
```

another common way is to normalize to range `<0,1>` which has the advantage that from RGB colors you can infere 3D direction... (like on normal/bump maps)

```
pixel(x,y) = 0.5 + 0.5*pixel(x,y)/max;
```

and back

```
pixel(x,y) = 2.0*max*pixel(x,y)-max;
```

Comment: I'm already using `GL_RGBA16F`, doesn't it work with negative values already? Sorry if my question was confusing, I'm looking for image formats such as in .jpg, .png, .hdr, etc because I want to save the image to disk. I will edit my question to make it more clear. Very interesting link btw