# OpenGL shader fill works with constant color, doesn't work with interpolation, how to debug?

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

We have code that mostly works filling polygons on a map, though it draws convex hulls and fills in some areas (will require tessellation).

The shader is given a set of triangle fan operations, and draws using hardcoded color yellow (and it works).

[image: picture of US map with yellow hardcoded fill]

Then we try to interpolate based on the value, and it turns black (does not work).
[image: same us map, shading from blue to red does not work]

Here is the fragment shader. Values coming in are all 0.0 to 1.0
With minVal = 0.0, maxVal = 1.0
and colors set to (0,0,1) and (1,0,0)
While I would appreciate knowing the bug, I would much more like to know how I can debug it. I need to be able to get the values in the shader and see what is happening. In short, I need some kind of debugging facility for GLSL. I did find NVIDIA nsight: https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics but could not get it working on linux.

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

//in vec2 TexCoord;
in float val;
//uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
uniform vec3 minColor;
uniform vec3 maxColor;
uniform float minVal;
uniform float maxVal;

void main()
{
    float f = (val - minVal)/ (maxVal-minVal);
    //FragColor = vec4(1,1,0,1);//texture(ourTexture, f);
    FragColor = vec4(minColor*(1.0-f) + maxColor * f,1.0);
}
```

Comment: `I would much more like to know how I can debug it.` Try [Renderdoc](https://renderdoc.org/)

Comment: renderdoc does not debug shaders though it is nice to know about it

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that we were using glUniform4fv to set a color with rgba.
There was no compile or runtime error. These calls do not have an error return that I know of.

The shader also did not generate an error, but the variables minColor and maxColor were not correctly set.

Thus the interpolation was always black.

```
vec4(minColor*(1.0-f) + maxColor * f,1.0);
```

There should have been an error, attempting to set an RGBA color into a vec3 variable.

I have found printf functions on stackoverflow that would have allowed viewing this kind of information: [Convert floating-point numbers to decimal digits in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793883/convert-floating-point-numbers-to-decimal-digits-in-glsl)