# Why I get different results from a cpu and gsgl rendered sobel filter by using the same algorithm?

Tags: c++, glsl, sobel

If I use this code:

```
QImage gradient_image(image_ptr->width(),image_ptr->height(),QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
//gradient_image.fill(Qt::red);

//sobel algorythm
double S_x [3] [3] = {{-1,0,1},{-2,0,2},{-1,0,[enter image description here][1]1}};
double S_y [3] [3] = {{-1,-2,-1},{0,0,0},{1,2,1}};
QPoint source_point(0,0);
double G_x = 0;
double G_y = 0;
int G = 0;
QColor source_color;
QRgb gradient_color;

for(int x= 0;x < image_ptr->width()-2;x++)
{

    for (int y = 0; y < image_ptr->height() - 2; y++)            
    {
    source_point.setX(x); source_point.setY(y);
    source_color = image_ptr->pixelColor(x,y);
    G_x = (S_x[0] [0] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x,y).red()) +
          (S_x [0] [1] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+1,y).red()) +
          (S_x [0] [2] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+2,y).red())+
          (S_x [1] [0] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x,y+1).red()) +
          (S_x [1] [1] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+1,y+1).red()) +
          (S_x [1] [2] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+2,y+1).red()) +
          (S_x [2] [0] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x,y+2).red()) +
          (S_x [2] [1] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+1,y+2).red()) +
          (S_x [2] [2] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+2,y+2).red());


    G_y =   (S_y[0] [0] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x,y).red()) +
            (S_y [0] [1] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+1,y).red()) +
            (S_y [0] [2] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+2,y).red())+
            (S_y [1] [0] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x,y+1).red()) +
            (S_y [1] [1] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+1,y+1).red()) +
            (S_y [1] [2] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+2,y+1).red()) +
            (S_y [2] [0] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x,y+2).red()) +
            (S_y [2] [1] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+1,y+2).red()) +
            (S_y [2] [2] * image_ptr->pixelColor(x+2,y+2).red());

    G = (int) qSqrt((G_x * G_x) + (G_y * G_y));
    //std::cout << "G is: " << G;
    gradient_color = qRgb(G,G,G);
    gradient_image.setPixel(x,y,gradient_color);


    }
```

I get this result:
[image]

I transfered the algorithm into gsgl:

```
uniform sampler2D   texture;
uniform float       width;
uniform float       height;
uniform float           threshold;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;


void main(void)
{
 mat3 Sx;
 mat3 Sy;
 Sx[0].xyz = vec3(1,0,-1);  Sx[1].xyz = vec3(2,0,-2); Sx[2].xyz = vec3(1,0,-1);
 Sy[0].xyz = vec3(1,2,1);   Sy[1].xyz = vec3(0,0,0);  Sy[2].xyz =vec3(-1,-2,-1);

 float w = 1.0 / width;
 float h = 1.0 / height;

 vec4 pos[9];
 pos[0] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord);//pixel
 pos[1] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(w,0));//x+1 y
 pos[2] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(2*w,0));//x+2  y
 pos[3] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(0,h));//y+1
 pos[4] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(w,h));//x+1 und  y+1
 pos[5] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(2*w,h));//x+2 y+1
 pos[6] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(0,2*h));//x   y+2
 pos[7] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(w,2*h));//x+1 y+2
 pos[8] = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord + vec2(2*w,2*h));//x+2 y+2


 //vec3 c;//c = colour from texture pixel.
 //c = texture2D(texture,vTexCoord);

 float Gx;
 float Gy;

  Gx = (Sx[0].x   * pos[0].r) + (Sx[0].y  * pos[1].r) + (Sx[0].z * pos[2].r) +
       (Sx[1].x * pos[3].r )  + (Sx[1].y * pos[4].r )+   (Sx[1].z * pos[5].r )+
       (Sx[2].x * pos[6].r )  + (Sx[2].y * pos[7].r ) +  (Sx[2].z * pos[8].r )  ;

  Gy = (Sy[0].x   * pos[0].r) + (Sy[0].y  * pos[1].r) + (Sy[0].z * pos[2].r) +
          (Sy[1].x * pos[3].r )  + (Sy[1].y * pos[4].r )+   (Sy[1].z * pos[5].r )+
          (Sy[2].x * pos[6].r )  + (Sy[2].y * pos[7].r ) +  (Sy[2].z * pos[8].r )  ;

   float sobel = sqrt((Gx*Gx) + (Gy * Gy));

 
   gl_FragColor = vec4( sobel,sobel,sobel,1.0 );



}
```

The result is:

[image]

I want that the glsl result looks like the first (the cpu) result.

What was my mistake ?

Comment: My guess would be because the c++ image is using integers but the glsl is floating point

Comment: Can you compare and list the intermediate results for one single pixel?

Comment: Please use comments for discussion, answers should be reserved for solutions. printf on glsl shaders: https://github.com/msqrt/shader-printf or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793883/convert-floating-point-numbers-to-decimal-digits-in-glsl/44797902#44797902 you can also (without additional code or libraries) choose one of your intermediate results and set the output pixel to just this value and later on see the pixel color value of this pixel (with some lens tool to get the numeric color value).

Comment: There are also extensions for your favorite debugger or IDE to step through GLSL code and see the contents of variables.

Comment: As intermediate result, you could just output Gx*Gx from CPU and GLSL and compare.